# Перехват исключения в итераторе PHP

Tags: php, исключения, итераторы, обработка-ошибок

Как можно перехватить исключение в итераторе при генерации элемента и продолжить обработку следующих?

```
function getItems() {
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= 10) {
        if ($i == 4) {
            throw new Exception("Item not found!");
        }
        yield $i++ * 2;
    }
}


try {
    $items = getItems();
    foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
        try {
            echo "$k -> $v\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error on item $k: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error on processing: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Вывод должен получиться такой:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 6
Error on item 4: Item not found!
5 -> 10
6 -> 12
7 -> 14
8 -> 16
9 -> 18
10 -> 20
```

Comment: как минимум стоит исправить синтаксические ошибки

Comment: @naumow Опечатался, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно узнать, что yield - это на самом деле класс generator, реализующий стандартный интерфейс [iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), т.е. по нему можно ходить руками выполняя те же самые действия, что и foreach:

```
function getItems() {
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= 30) {
        if ($i == 4) {
            throw new Exception("Item not found!");
        }
        yield $i++;
    }
}

$it = getItems();
$it->rewind();

while ($it->valid())
{
    try {
        $k = $it->key();
        $v = $it->current();
        echo "$k -> $v\n";

        $it->next();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error on item $k: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        var_dump($it->valid());
    }
}
```

Откуда можно узнать, что бросание исключения из функции, реализующий yield принудительно инвалидирует итератор. После throw в getItems обратной дороги уже нет. Пропустить элемент в цикле по генератору так нельзя.

Актуально и для php 5.6 и для 7.0.

Придётся вам изменять логику кода, например, реализовывать свой полноценный iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Что мы  сейчас имеем?

```
<?php

function getItems() {
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= 10) {
        if ($i == 4) {
            throw new Exception("Item not found!");
        }
        yield $i++ * 2;
    }
}


try {
    $items = getItems(); 
    // я посылаю искл, а следовательно исполняю самый нижний Exception

    foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
        try {
            echo "$k -> $v\n";
            // как echo может бросить исключение в данном случае???
            // переделаем.
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // исключение никогда не исполнится, echo бросать искл особо не умеет
            echo "Error on item $k: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error on processing: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n"; 
    //<-------- отработка искл, которое бросило getItems()
}
```

*Мне идея скрипта не ясна. Поэтому я сделал так.*

```
function getItems() {
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= 10) {
        #if ($i == 4) {
        #    throw new Exception("Item not found!");
        #}
        yield $i++ * 2;
    }
}


$items = getItems();
foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
    try {
        if($k == 4){
            throw new Exception("Item not found!");
        }
        echo "$k -> $v\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error on item $k: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 6
Error on item 4: Item not found!
5 -> 10
6 -> 12
7 -> 14
8 -> 16
9 -> 18
10 -> 20
```